# How to create internal links for a TOC of PDF?

Tags: pdf

How do we create internal links for the existing TOC of a (text) PDF file on Linux?

Comment: Welcome to SU. TOCs are usually done in the application that created the original file. You can try to open the file in a text processing application like LibreOffice Writer and if successful, create TOC there and export a new PDF.  Alternatively you can install a PDF editor and see if you can do it there.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Not possible automatically, as far as I am aware. As a poor second, if your PDFs have document outlines, you can use a tool which typesets a new table of contents from the document outline and adds it to the front of the document. For example `cpdf -table-of-contents in.pdf -o out.pdf`